# How to define a unique json column in sqlalchemy? (postgres)

Tags: json, sqlalchemy

I'd like to define a unique json column via sqlalchemy on postgres. the naive approach did not work:

this:

```
values = db.Column(db.JSON(), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

led to this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) data type json has no default operator class for access method "btree"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column that will receive the json md5 hash:

```
hash_values = db.Column(db.String(32), default="")
```

Declare the combination of the json field and the hash as unique:

```
__table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('values', 'hash_values'))
```

Staying like this:

```
import json
import hashlib

class Register(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'register'

    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('values', 'hash_values'),
    )

    values = db.Column(db.JSON, default="{}")
    hash_values = db.Column(db.String(32), default="")

    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
        self.hash_values = hashlib.md5(
                json.dumps(
                    values,
                    sort_keys=True
                ).encode("utf-8")
            ).hexdigest()
```

Comment: works only if enforce uniqueness on hash.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you import JSON from sqlalchemy as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import JSON
```

I think calling sqlalchemy JSON type should work. You could try something like this:

```
values = db.Column(JSON, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Remember the base types.JSON provides keyed index operations, integer index operations and path index operations.

For more information [see this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately what you're suggesting is _exactly_ what I tried - and that does not work.